# Problem with ssh connection to private Git Repo

Tags: git, ssh

I have my own server where I host my git repositories.
without any changes on my side, git connection became problematic. My current guess is that the last update for git is responsible.

I got a warning about the ssh key being not save enough anymore.
Before I was using an rsa sha-1 key, so i updated it to ecdsa 512.

I can connect via ssh just fine but git doesn't work.

The following error is thrown on any git command

```
Permission denied (publickey).
stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Does anyone know what could be the reason for this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

For testing, check the content of the ~git/.bashrc (or .zshrc, depending on its default shell), and add, as [in this issue](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto/issues/1770):

```
stty -F/dev/tty -ixon -ixoff
```

Check if the issue persists then.

Comment: @maxpert what is the default shell used when you log on with ssh? Did you modify the resource file on the remote machine (not the local one)?

Comment: yeah the remote one. Locally i usea windows machine.